# detecting weak equivalences in a simplicial model category II

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories

The question is related to the question:    [detecting weak equivalences in a simplicial model category](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309538/detecting-weak-equivalences-in-a-simplicial-model-category/309546?noredirect=1#comment771217_309546)

Suppose that we have a simplicial model category $M$ and denote by $M^{f}$ the full simplicial subcategory of fibrant objects. Suppose that $R$ is a subcategory of $M^{f}$ such that for any object $m\in M^{f}$ there exists an object $r\in R$ such that $r$ is (zigzag) equivalent to $m$ i.e. $r$ and $m$ are isomorphic in $Ho(M)$ the homotopy category of $M$. Let $w: a\rightarrow b$ be a morphism in $M$ such that for any object $r\in R$ the induced map of simplicial sets $w^{\ast}:Map_{M}(b,r)\rightarrow Map_{M}(a,r)$ is a weak homotopy equivalence of simplicial sets. 
Can we conclude that $w$ is a weak equivalence in the model category $M$ ?

If $R=M^{f}$ this is true and is proved in Hirschhorn's book.

**EDIT :** The question is very general, and it should have a formal answer in case it is true. After trying all suggestions (in the comments and deleted answer) and reading Hirshorn's book  I had the impression that maybe the answer to my question is **no**, and there should be a counterexample. In the Hirshorn's book the fact we test for all fibrant objects seems to be essential.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, essentially the same argument as in Hirschhorn's book should give an affirmative answer to your question. (First do a cofibrant-fibrant replacement of a and b, then do a fibrant replacement of w; apply the argument to this replacement of w.)

Comment: @skd I'm a beginner in the field,  I tried your suggestion, I was unable to provide a correct proof. I feel I'm missing some thing... Any help with more detail is welcome.

Comment: I agree with OP. The question is not that simple and the answer might as well be no. It seems that @skd's suggestion doesn't work because we need to take cofibrant fibrant replacements of a and b which belong to $R$, but I think we can't choose such a replacement in general.

Comment: Probably this can be proven if every object is cofibrant. So when looking for counterexamples, it's probably best to look at simplicial model categories where not every object is cofibrant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following gives a counterexample:

Take the category of morphisms in $\operatorname{SSet}$, i.e., the category $\operatorname{Fun}(C,\operatorname{SSet}),$ where $C$ is the category with two objects and one non-identity morphism. Equip this category with the projective model structure. $R$ will be the category of morphisms $f:X\rightarrow Y$ where $X,Y$ are Kan complexes and $f$ is a $\operatorname{SSet}$-cofibration (i.e., monomorphism.)

Let $a$ correspond to the morphism $\operatorname{Sing}(S^1)\rightarrow\Delta^0$ and let $b$ correspond to the morphism $\Delta^0\rightarrow\Delta^0.$

If I haven't made a mistake, with these choices, $\operatorname{Map}(b,r)\rightarrow\operatorname{Map}(a,r)$ is even an isomorphism for all $r\in R$. Every fibrant object in $\operatorname{Fun}(C,\operatorname{SSet})$ is equivalent to an object of $R$ (factor your morphism into a cofibration+trivial fibration and take the trivial fibration part.)